# mod_wsgi is compiled in one version and running in a different version even after following the given steps

Tags: apache, webserver, mod-wsgi

I am getting an error when I run the apache server through my client after going through the log I understood that the mod_wsgi uses python 2.6 during compiling and uses python 2.7 for running. After some research in the Internet I followed the below steps:

## You have to recompile mod-python and/or mod-wsgi.

## Remove mods

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

## Get dependencies

```
apt-get build-dep libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

## Build mod-python

```
mkdir /tmp/python
cd /tmp/python
apt-get source libapache2-mod-python
cd libapache2-mod-python-[x.x.x]
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
```

## Build mod-wsgi

```
mkdir /tmp/wsgi
cd /tmp/wsgi
apt-get source libapache2-mod-wsgi
cd mod-wsgi-[x.x.x]
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
```

## Install newly compiled packages

dpkg -i /tmp/python/libapache2-mod-python-[x.x].deb /tmp/wsgi/libapache2-mod-wsgi-[x.x].deb

It was of no use, now the version has changed to 3.2, I am worried about the space being consumed through the above steps and now the compiling python has changes to python 3.2 from 2.6 but the python used for running is still 2.7. please help me with what to do ? to get back my apache server running successfully.

error.log::::

```
[Wed Aug 21 11:48:11 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Wed Aug 21 11:48:11 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Wed Aug 21 11:48:11 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 21 11:48:36 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down


[Wed Aug 21 22:48:29 2013] [error] child process 1226 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Aug 21 22:48:30 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Aug 21 22:56:17 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Wed Aug 21 22:56:17 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Wed Aug 21 22:56:17 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 22 01:32:12 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Aug 22 01:32:26 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Thu Aug 22 01:32:26 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Thu Aug 22 01:32:26 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 22 04:04:48 2013] [notice] child pid 11212 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Aug 22 04:04:48 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Aug 22 04:04:56 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 6 max processes and 25 max threads.
[Thu Aug 22 04:04:56 2013] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp  
[Thu Aug 22 04:04:56 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.2.3.
[Thu Aug 22 04:04:56 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Thu Aug 22 04:04:56 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.3      mod_wsgi/3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't load mod_python and mod_wsgi at the same time if you don't need to. They are likely compiled against different Python versions. See the following for an explanation of the mismatch you are seeing.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Python_Version_Mismatch

If you do need both, they must both be compiled for the same version.

These days there is generally no good reason to be using mod_python for new projects.

Comment: Can you please tell me the best way of removing mod_python ? And I followed the above steps and downloaded couple of modules that is mod-wsgi and mod-python. Can you please tell me a best way to get rid of this if they are not useful ?

Comment: Presumably the same command you said you used to remove it in the first place. 'apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python'

Answer (score 0):

Just to add 
I have uninstalled libapache2-mod-python

```
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python
```

which I have installed 
then I have overcome the above error

```
[Thu Aug 22 01:32:26 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Thu Aug 22 01:32:26 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
```